# Performance of FetchMode.SELECT with FetchType.EAGER in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, pagination, criteria

I have two entities: Page and Comment

```
public class Page{
    private int     id;
    private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "page")
    public List<Comment> getComments() { return comments }
}

public class Comment {
    private int     id;
    private String  msgText;
    private Page page;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="page_id")
    public Page getPage() { return page }
}
```

Page maintains a collection of comments. Every time I fetch a page, I want to have all the comments loaded together with it, so I need to use **FetchType.EAGER**.
By default, this uses FetchMode.JOIN

The problem is that JOIN messes up the pagination - when I set the limit to 5, I get the first post as well as 4 comments (or 5 comments, I forget). Instead, I should get the first 5 posts as well as all of their comments.

So instead I decided to use **FetchMode.SELECT**.

**My questions**:

1. What is the difference in performance between FetchMode.SELECT together with FetchType.EAGER, and FetchMode.JOIN?
2. I know that FetchType.LAZY can lead to the N+1 queries problem. Does this problem occur when using FetchMode.SELECT with FetchType.EAGER? (ie - when I load a collection of pages, how many queries will it
   take to immediately load all their associated comments?)
3. Does it have any effect to specify Batch Size when using FetchMode.SELECT with FetchType.EAGER?

Comment: Turn on SQL logging and you'll be able to answer all your own questions. Performance differences we can offer are going to be meaningless opinions to you and your app as it will depend on a large number of variables that are specific to your application, data and database. The only way to determine what the performance differences would be with various options is to test with real world data in a real world system and compare.

Comment: @Chris I disagree that all my questions can be answered by turning on SQL logging. Hibernate documentation doesn't provide much insight on this and I want to learn the best practices from people who have experience with this.